# NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M with Bumblebee on Ubuntu 13.10 giving error

Tags: drivers, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have an Acer Aspire V7 running Ubuntu 13.10 with an NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M graphics card. Currently though I'm not using this at all I'm just using the standard Integrated Haswell Graphics. I've tried installing the Bumblebee package by following the instructions [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation) but whenever I try to run an application using the NVIDIA card I get the following error message:

```
[ 1641.382331] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:1:0:0.  Please

[ 1641.382365] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Acer Acpire V5 with GeForce GT 750M and Haswell. And optirun say the same error on first run. But on every second run it works fine.

```
$ optirun glxgears -info
[ 6640.693237] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:1:0:0.  Please
[ 6640.693272] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
$ optirun glxgears -info
GL_RENDERER   = GeForce GT 750M/PCIe/SSE2
GL_VERSION    = 4.3.0 NVIDIA 319.76
GL_VENDOR     = NVIDIA Corporation
...
```

Bumblebee 3.2.1, Xserver-intel 2.99.906, Linux kernel 3.13, Mesa 10.1.0.